Have Betti numbers $b_k=b_{n−k}$, and $b_{n/2}$ is even if $n$ is even. Construct an n-dimensional closed, oriented manifold with these Betti numbers.
Edit: After it being made clear that I didn't understand the question prompt, I have re-attempted the problem here.
This question is from a publicly available old qualifying exam (Stanford geometry and topology), which I am using to help learn this field. I consulted Hatcher's book for this problem, but I have seen no proof for this problem anywhere; all work is my own.


Let $b_0, b_1, \dots , b_n$ be a sequence of positive integers satisfying $b_k = b_{n−k}$ for all $k$, and $b_{n/2}$ is even if $n$ is even. Construct an n-dimensional closed, oriented manifold with these Betti numbers.

Answer: Have our n-dimensional manifold $M$ be the disjoint union of two n-spheres. That is: $$ M = S^n + S^n$$ Then the Betti number $b_j$ is given as $$ b_j = \begin{cases} 2 & \text{if } j = 0, n \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases} $$
Clearly $b_0 = b_{n-0}$, and for any $j \in (1, \dots, n-1)$, we have that $b_{j} = b_{n-j} = 0$. Thus our first condition has been met.
For our second condition, note that $b_{0/2} = b_0 =2$ is even. For $j \in \{ 1, \dots , n-1 \}$, it holds that $b_j = b_{j/2} = 0 $ is even. Similarly, if we have an even $n$, then $n/2 \in \{1, \dots , n-1\}$, so $b_{n/2} =0$ which is even. Thus our second condition is satisfied.

(a) Is the disjoint of two n-spheres a valid answer for this problem?
As a bonus, if there are any other constructions or techniques you want to bring up, I'd be happy to see them. Thanks in advance.

The point of the problem as stated is to find a manifold realizing any sequence of numbers satisfying the given constraints, not just some such sequence.

@TabesBridges Do you think so? From my interpretation, it seems certain that your construction has to satisfy any value of $n$, but I didn't think it needed to satisfy any possible sequence. You merely had to show that your n-dimensional construction satisfied the requirements. What would you do to construct a manifold that satisfies any possible sequence?

Yes, the sequence $b_0,\dotsc,b_n$ is given and you're supposed to construct a manifold realizing that sequence. Let me also point out that $b_0,b_n$ must be strictly positive, but the other numbers only need be non-negative. As for how to approach a solution, my hint is to consider both the disjoint union and the connected sum operation and see what they do to the Betti numbers.

@Thorgott Relating to the following asymmetry? For our oriented manifolds. the disjoint union is always the direct sum in all homology groups, whereas the connected sum is the the disjoint union in all nonzero homology groups, but is idempotent on the zeroth homology group?

You're slightly off, re-examine the top homology of the connected sum (also, using orientability is crucial here).
